# React Native local notifications and foreground service

Tags: android, react-native

I am developing a fitness app in react native.

I want to develop a rest timer feature for users to use to set rest time between workouts.

When the rest time ends, I want to send the user a local notification.

To make sure the user receives the notification even when the app in not in the foreground in Android, should I try to implement Android's Foreground Service? or WorkManager?

I have read the documentation and have seen some youtube videos on this but am not sure..

What would make sure the users get the notifications without the OS delaying them?

Answer (score 0):

[AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager) should be used for precise alarms.

> Unlike WorkManager, AlarmManager wakes a device from Doze mode. It is therefore not efficient in terms of power and resource management. Only use it for precise alarms or notifications such as calendar events — not background work.

See [Set an exact alarm](https://developer.android.com/develop/background-work/services/alarms/schedule#exact) for details.

Answer (score 0):

As like @user18309290 said AlarmManager is the best choice to do it.
I recommend to use [react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).
You don't need other steps in installation specifically to implement only local notification.

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
...
   when: null, // (optional) Add a timestamp (Unix timestamp value in milliseconds) pertaining to the notification (usually the time the event occurred). For apps targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.N and above, this time is not shown anymore by default and must be opted into by using `showWhen`, default: null.
...
})
```